# Dynamically insert results of sp_executesql into table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've written the following TSQL:-

```
declare @sql nvarchar(1000)
set @sql = N'select top 5 BusinessEntityID, PersonType from AdventureWorks2008R2.Person.Person'

create table #temp(BusinessEntityID int, PersonType varchar(10))
insert into #temp execute sp_executesql @statement=@sql
select * from #temp
```

This creates a temporary table with the two columns identified in @sql, and then inserts the rows of data into it, but I need to identify the columns in the create table statement first.

Is there a way to do this without prior knowledge of the columns?  I'd like to be able to set @sql to any valid select statement but not have to map the columns in the create table statement.  I've tried looking at using `select into` but I'm completely stuck now.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: [Naive approach](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/376847)

Answer (score 1):

SELECT INTO would be the only to do this. You can't use dynamic sql the way you are trying to. The select into portion would have to be part of the dynamic sql.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(1000)
set @sql = N'select top 5 BusinessEntityID, PersonType 
into MyNewTable 
from AdventureWorks2008R2.Person.Person'

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

I have to ask. Why do you need to use dynamic sql here at all? There is no reason to use this from what you posted. This could be greatly simplified to the following. No dynamic sql required at all.

```
select top 5 BusinessEntityID, PersonType 
    into MyNewTable 
    from AdventureWorks2008R2.Person.Person
```

Comment: SELECT INTO to normal table is some solution, but what with temps tables?

Comment: What I've written is a part of a stored procedure I'm writing.  As part of the parameters of the sp I want to provide a sql select statement that the sp then works on, and for that I need the data in a temp table.

Comment: You can insert into a temp just the same.

Comment: No you can't. In dynamic sql you create new context and temp table cease to exist when dynamic-sql is executed.

Comment: And I get `Invalid object name '#MyTempTable'.` Great demo :)

Comment: Yes you can go the other way and my brain got backwards...thank goodness its friday. :)

Comment: I have to say that passing a sql statement to a procedure is not a good design approach. It brings a lot of challenges and vulnerabilities that could probably be avoided with a more traditional approach.